# kafka consumers reading and writing to same partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

can 2 consumers from different groups read from the same topic and partition x and than both write into another topic and partition y?

I would implement a consumer strategy in which one consumer discards data that the other consumer processes.
The order in which the data is persisted by the producers into the shared partition is not important.

i just want to know if this is possible

Comment: A consumer only reads and does not write.  But you can certainly have two consumers read from the same topic and pass their results to a producer that writes to another common topic. They will each read each input record (everything is read twice, once by each consumer group, but you can implement custom logic to have them ignore what only the other one should get to see -- though depending on how much you'd be skipping that way two separate input topics or a single consumer group that does both things may be a better way).

Comment: yes sorry i was meaning producers writing into topics. thx for the help

Comment: If you want one consumer to ignore the input from the second one, why not using the same group? This would avoid you al the troublesome from dealing with synchronization.
If your issue is that the input data is in a single partition (and that you can't change that), simply use kafka stream (or a simple client) to spread your data from your topic/partition to a new topic/2* partitions, round robin way. Then you can effectively have two consumers on it.

Comment: 2nd part sounds intreging. but first part is wrong i think. as  i understand 2 consumers in one group cannot read from the same topic. the 2nd consumer will just be backup for when the 1st consumer goes  offline or sth like it

Answer (score 1):

You could have two different approaches here :

- The consumers are in different consumer groups. It means that both will receive all messages and it's up to your business logic to ignore some message for a consumer while the other is processing them
- The consumers are in the same consumer group so that they'll receive different partitions and you have messages delivered to a consumer a not to the other. You are leveraging a Kafka feature but it depends on how you will "partition" your data if using the default round robin way or using a key per message or a custom partitioner.

The only concern I see in the second solution is the rebalance. If a consumer goes offline and then comes back, a rebalance happens and the partitions could be distributed in a different way. I.e. you start having consumer C1 reading from partitions P1 and P2 and C2 reading from partitions P3 and P4. Imagine that C2 goes offline. First of all if it's offline for more time, the C1 will get all partitions (I don't know if it's good for your scenario) but when C2 comes back online the rebalance happens and assigned partitions could be different, i.e. P1 and P2 assigned to C2 (not C1 anymore) and P3 and P4 to C1 (not C2 anymore); it depends if this sort of consumers swap on partitions is a problem for your application logic.